# Math.round(6.079084800080882E-5) = 0.0?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to round this number

```
6.079084800080882E-5
```

But whenever I'm running the app, the result is this

```
X = 0.0
```

This is my code

```
tmp = 6.079084800080882E-5;
x = (double)Math.round(tmp);
```

I'm not just entering a random number (6.079084800080882E-5), but this is a nuber generated from some calculations before hand. Those calculations shouldn't matter, as this is the number I'm trying to round.

Comment: what type are `tmp` and `x` ?

Comment: what were you expecting?

Comment: It looks like it's been rounded.

Comment: How many decimal places do you want this to be rounded..?

Comment: Both tmp and x are doubles. I'm expecting 6.00. I want 2 decimals

Comment: Use `String s = String.format("%.2f", tmp);` then.

Comment: Hah nevermind. It's just me and maths, we don't get alng very well. ofc, this is 0.00006079084....

Comment: @Detilium You mean 6.00E-5, right? You're dealing with a fairly small number here. It's not clear you understand that. The expected *rounding* would be 6.08E-5.

Answer (score 14):

`Math.round()` returns either a `long` or an `int`, so if you pass to it a number whose absolute value is smaller than 0.5, you'll get 0. 0 is very round.

Answer (score 5):

This has to be 0, because 6.079084800080882E-5= 0.000060790084000.
E-5 means 10^(-5).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed already out, `Math.round()` works as standard round, therefore always get you rid of any decimal places and returns the whole number.

If you need round to specific number of decimal places, this is what you need

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class RoundingExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double tmp = 6.079084800080882E-5;
        System.out.println(round(tmp, 3));
        System.out.println(round(tmp, 4));
        System.out.println(round(tmp, 5));
        System.out.println(round(tmp, 6));
        System.out.println(round(tmp, 7));
    }

    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Code above having this output

```
0.0
1.0E-4
6.0E-5
6.1E-5
6.08E-5
```